# Fréchet derivative, is this true?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functional-analysis

I was just wondering whether the following statement is true:

Let $H_1,H_2$ be Hilbert spaces and $\{e_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H_2$. Let $f:H_1\rightarrow H_2$ be an operator (not necessarily linear) and $\pi_n:H_2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the $n$-th projection, i.e. $\pi_n(y) = \langle y,e_n\rangle, y\in H_2$. Then if $\pi_n f$ is Fréchet differentiable for all $n\geq 0$, so is $f$ too.

I just wonder if the above statement is true even if we need to add more conditions. The question is essentially how to pass from the finite dimensional projections to the whole space $H_2$.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Do you assume that the Fréchet derivative is bounded? If yes, then the linear map $\ell^2 \to \ell^2$, $(x_1,x_2, x_3 \cdots ) \to (x_1, 2x_2, 3x_3, \cdots)$ satisfies your condition but is not differentiable.

Comment: In that case we should add one more condition :) namely, that the Fréchet derivative is in addition bounded. Would that be enough? I also have the impression that one should have something like $\{D(\pi_nf)\}_{n\geq 0}\in \ell_1(\mathbb{N},L(H_2,\mathbb{R}))$, i.e. that the sequence is summable or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An additional error condition is needed such that it should be easy to identify sufficient conditions, but it may not be obvious what the necessary ones are.

Passing to the coordinates in the orthonormal basis, we can write everything in coordinate vector form $f(x) = ( \pi_n f(x))_n$. Then

$$ f(x+h) - f(x) = ( \pi_n f(x+h) - \pi_n f(x))_n$$

By Frechet differentiability, each projection satisfies

$$ \pi_n f(x+h) - \pi_n f(x) = D_n f(x)h + E_n(h) $$

where $E_n(h) = o(h)$. And therefore

$$ f(x+h) - f(x) = (D_n f(x)h + E_n(h))_n = (D_n f(x))_n h + (E_n(h))_n$$

Therefore a sufficient set of conditions is that $Df = (D_nf(x))_n$ is a bounded linear operator if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \| D_nf\|^2 < \infty$, and that we have an error that is $o(h)$, which is satisfied if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \| E_n(h)\|^2 / \|h\|^2 \rightarrow 0$ as $\|h\| \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Here when you write $D_n$ you mean $D_nf := D\pi_n f$ right? and you need that this sequence is in $\ell^2$, I imagined something like that. Is there any closer expression for this term $E_n(h)$? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, I do mean that. And for $E_n(h)$, all we know is that it is $o(h)$. So, for example, if $\|E_n(h)\| = h^2$ for every $n$, then each projection would be differentiable, but since this higher order error does not decay, then the full function is not differentiable since the higher order error fails to be $o(h)$.